# React Ant Design defaultValue from state does not work

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am following Ant design for react [official docs](https://ant.design/components/select/) where they have hard-coded the default value in the select element inline:

```
defaultValue={['a10', 'c12']}
```

I am trying to use the exact same value from react state and it does not show up at all. If i use `value` instead of `defaultValue` then it (same value from state) shows up but it's not editable so using `value` is not an option.

So basically I have to use `defaultValue` as shown in the docs but I am totally surprised that it does not render at all. However if I hard code the exact same data `['a10', 'c12']` it works fine! What is the catch here? Have anyone come across such issue?

Please see the screenshots below. Thanks.

Screenshot 1. values hard coded in the state and it works, the select fields are populated

Screenshot 2. tried using useEffect to update the state (eventually this data will come from API) instead of hardcoding but it does not appear in select fields. but you can see in `JSON.stringify()` there is value in the state

Screenshot 3. This is how I have used defaultValue as shown in docs

[image: values hard coded in the state and it works, the select fields are populated]

[image: state value not showing in select]

[image: use of defaultValue in ant design select]

Answer (score 4):

`useEffect` is usually run after the component is mounted/updated. `defaultValue` is only used on the initial render of the component. Hence in your case 1, where the state is hard coded, the value showed up since the default value was provided during the input's(select) initial render.

In the case where the state is updated in `useEffect`, the state won't reflect because, the initial render of the input is done already and the defaultValue will not be used here after for the specific input. In case you need state to control the value of the input(select), try passing `value` to Input instead of `defaultValue`. This makes the component to be controlled.

Comment: Multiple names using value, instead of defaultValue is not editable. Is there a way to prepopulate state values inline just like in examples and have them editable?

Comment: could not understand your requirements.. 

Comment: If I use value instead of defaultValue, then it’s not editable

Comment: Yup. You need to handle the `onChange` event. The onChange would be triggered and you have to update the state during that call. The docs should have an example. Unless you update the state, new values would not go in. This is how controlled components work.

Comment: Ok will try. Thx

Comment: Or if you need to use `defaultValue` only, then you can defer the render of the `select` component. Render it conditionally only if you see a value  in defaultValue. Choice is yours 

Comment: I tried conditionally, didn’t work. Can you please share the solution using some open source api to demonstrate. I’m basically trying to update a product where I want to show all its categories pre-populated in the select box in editable format. We can talk offline if you are interested:)

Comment: Conditionally is basically you wrap the component in something like this `{ existingSubCategories && <Select ..props />}`. You have to initialize the `existingSubCategories with null or undefined. In case you initialize it with empty array, you might also need to add length check to see if data is present in the array before rendering

Comment: here is a simple example from the react offical docs that shows conditional rendering. https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ozJddz?editors=0010. Try changing the `messages` to empty array and see the condition is falsey and not rendering the relevant part

Comment: I have tried conditional rendering already :) .lengh && it’s not working

Comment: Maybe you can fork docs example in codepen and use real api to fetch todos and render with defaultValue

Comment: You can try this api to get todos: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

Comment: Here is a simple example.. https://codepen.io/marudhupandiyang/pen/oNjqqxY?editors=0010

Comment: Here is what you are looking for
https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-selection-for-stackoverflow-o652u